# VB.NET Group by two columns and write results to an array

Tags: vb.net, linq, csv, group-by

I need to group csv data to new csv by column values. I can do it by only one column, but unfortunately it is not enough, because I got duplicates and not achieve my goal. Here is my csv example, there is about 50 columns and last here is column(29) in my input csv:

```
603;10453;2.12.2020;88,69
603;10453;2.12.2020;88,69
603;10453;4.12.2020;72,69
605;10441;3.12.2020;39,51
605;10441;8.12.2020;25,85
605;10441;9.12.2020;52,91
605;10441;10.12.2020;66,31
605;10441;10.12.2020;66,31
606;10453;11.12.2020;72,69
606;10453;11.12.2020;72,69
607;11202;1.12.2020;250,98
607;11202;1.12.2020;250,98
607;11202;1.12.2020;250,98
607;11202;1.12.2020;250,98
607;11202;1.12.2020;250,98
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;3.12.2020;165,29
607;11202;3.12.2020;165,29
607;11202;3.12.2020;165,29
607;11202;3.12.2020;165,29
607;11202;4.12.2020;75,87
607;11202;5.12.2020;123,24
607;11202;5.12.2020;123,24
607;11202;5.12.2020;123,24
607;11202;7.12.2020;88,69
607;11202;7.12.2020;88,69
```

And here is my code, where I group values by last column:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim inputFile = "input.csv"
        Dim outputFile = "output.csv"


        IO.File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, IO.File.ReadLines(inputFile).
                        Select(Function(x) x.Split(";"c)).
                        GroupBy(Function(x) {x(0), x(3)}).
                    Select(Function(x)
                               Return String.Format(
                                "{0};{1};{2};{3}",
                                x.Select(Function(y) y(0)).First,
                                x.Select(Function(y) y(1)).First,
                                x.Select(Function(y) y(2)).First,
                                x.Select(Function(y) y(3)).First)
                               End Function).ToArray)
    End Sub
```

As you can see in the last column duplicate values and I need group this file by two keys, one of them column(0) or column(1) values and second one is column(3). But I can't figure out how I can I do it with my code.
Desiret outout file have to looks like this:

```
603;10453;2.12.2020;88,69
603;10453;4.12.2020;72,69
605;10441;3.12.2020;39,51
605;10441;8.12.2020;25,85
605;10441;9.12.2020;52,91
605;10441;10.12.2020;66,31
606;10453;11.12.2020;72,69
607;11202;1.12.2020;250,98
607;11202;2.12.2020;274,02
607;11202;3.12.2020;165,29
607;11202;4.12.2020;75,87
607;11202;5.12.2020;123,24
607;11202;7.12.2020;88,69
```

Usualy I have to remove duplicates if column(0) and column(2) if they has match.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Show what the output file should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work. For my goal I used Christoph example. Finaly my code looks like this:

```
Public Class TempClass
        Public Property ID As String
        Public Property day As String
        Public Property OriginalStr As String
        End Class
Public Class TempIDComparer
            Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TempClass)

            Private Function IEqualityComparer_Equals(x As TempClass, y As TempClass) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TempClass).Equals
            If ReferenceEquals(x, y) Then
                Return True
            End If
            If ReferenceEquals(x, Nothing) OrElse ReferenceEquals(y, Nothing) Then
                Return False
            End If

            Return x.ID = y.ID AndAlso x.day = y.day
        End Function
            Private Function IEqualityComparer_GetHashCode(obj As TempClass) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TempClass).GetHashCode
                If obj Is Nothing Then Return 0
                Return obj.ID.GetHashCode()
            End Function
        End Class

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim inputFile = "input.csv"
        Dim outputFile = "output.csv"


        Dim list As List(Of TempClass) = New List(Of TempClass)()
        Dim ls As List(Of String()) = New List(Of String())()
        Dim fileReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(inputFile)
        Dim strLine As String = ""

        While strLine IsNot Nothing
            strLine = fileReader.ReadLine()

            If strLine IsNot Nothing AndAlso strLine.Length > 0 Then
                Dim t As TempClass = New TempClass() With {
                        .ID = strLine.Split(";"c)(0),
                        .day = strLine.Split(";"c)(3),
                        .OriginalStr = strLine
                    }
                list.Add(t)
            End If
        End While

        fileReader.Close()
        Dim tempList = list.Distinct(New TempIDComparer())
        Dim fileWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(outputFile, False, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        For Each item In tempList.ToList()
            fileWriter.WriteLine(item.OriginalStr)
        Next
        fileWriter.Flush()
        fileWriter.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an object oriented approach. Make a wrapper object around each line that does the parsing and provides properties for each value, and then group the result as desired (I choose again the object oriented approach with an equality comparer and `distinct`).

As I don't know the meaning of the columns I simply assumed something: `OrderNo`, `CustomerNo`, `OrderDate` and `Value`.

Here's the code for the wrapper class:

```
Private Class Record

    'Constructors
    Public Sub New(lineNo As Int32, line As String)
        Const expectedColumnCount As Int32 = 4
        Const delimiter As String = ";"
        If (lineNo < 1) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(NameOf(lineNo), lineNo, "The line number must be positive!")
        If (line Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(line))
        Dim tokens As String() = Split(line, delimiter, expectedColumnCount + 1, CompareMethod.Binary)
        If (tokens.Length <> expectedColumnCount) Then Throw New ArgumentException($"Line {lineNo}: Invalid data row! {expectedColumnCount} '{delimiter}'-delimitered columns expected.")
        Me.Tokens = tokens
    End Sub

    'Public Properties

    Public ReadOnly Property OrderNo As String
        Get
            Return Tokens(0)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property CustomerNo As String
        Get
            Return Tokens(1)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property OrderDate As String
        Get
            Return Tokens(2)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As String
        Get
            Return Tokens(3)
        End Get
    End Property

    'Private Properties

    Private ReadOnly Property Tokens As String()

End Class
```

And this is the comparer that does the grouping:

```
Private Class RecordComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Record)

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Singleton As New RecordComparer()

    Public Function Equals(x As Record, y As Record) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Record).Equals
        If (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) Then Return True
        If (x Is Nothing) OrElse (y Is Nothing) Then Return False
        Return Comparer.Equals(x.OrderNo, y.OrderNo) AndAlso Comparer.Equals(x.CustomerNo, y.CustomerNo) AndAlso Comparer.Equals(x.Value, y.Value)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode(obj As Record) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Record).GetHashCode
        If (obj Is Nothing) Then Return 42
        Return Comparer.GetHashCode(obj.OrderNo) Xor Comparer.GetHashCode(obj.CustomerNo) Xor Comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Value)
    End Function

    Private Shared ReadOnly Comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of String) = StringComparer.Ordinal

End Class
```

and finally the usage:

```
    'Convert input lines to simple objects
    Dim i As Int32 = 1
    Dim dataRows As New List(Of Record)()
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(inputFile)
        Dim data As New Record(i, line)
        dataRows.Add(data)
        i += 1
    Next
    'Group by the 3 columns (the DateTime is kind of random, no guarantee which object wins)
    Dim consolidatedRows As IEnumerable(Of Record) = dataRows.Distinct(SimpleInputDataComparer.Singleton)
    'Convert and export lines
    Dim outputLines As IEnumerable(Of String) = consolidatedRows.Select(Function(e) $"{e.OrderNo};{e.CustomerNo};{e.OrderDate};{e.Value}")
    File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, outputLines)
```